# How to use async countdown event instead of collecting tasks and awaiting on them?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I have the following code:

```
var tasks = await taskSeedSource
    .Select(taskSeed => GetPendingOrRunningTask(taskSeed, createTask, onFailed, onSuccess, sem))
    .ToList()
    .ToTask();

if (tasks.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}

if (tasks.Contains(null))
{
    tasks = tasks.Where(t => t != null).ToArray();
    if (tasks.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Where `taskSeedSource` is a Reactive Observable. It could be that this code have many problems, but I see at least two:

1. I am collecting tasks whereas I could do without it.
2. Somehow, the returned tasks list may contain nulls, even though `GetPendingOrRunningTask` is an `async` method and hence never returns `null`. I failed to understand why it happens, so I had to defend against it without understanding the cause of the problem.

I would like to use the `AsyncCountdownEvent` from the [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) framework instead of collecting the tasks and then awaiting on them.

So, I can pass the countdown event to `GetPendingOrRunningTask` which will increment it immediately and signal before returning after awaiting for the completion of its internal logic. However, I do not understand how to integrate the countdown event into the monad (that is the Reactive jargon, isn't it?).

What is the right way to do it?

**EDIT**

Guys, let us forget about the mysterious nulls in the returned list. Suppose everything is green and the code is

```
var tasks = await taskSeedSource
    .Select(taskSeed => GetPendingOrRunningTask(taskSeed, ...))
    .ToList()
    .ToTask();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Now the question is how do I do it with the countdown event? So, suppose I have:

```
var c = new AsyncCountdownEvent(1);
```

and

```
async Task GetPendingOrRunningTask<T>(AsyncCountdownEvent c, T taskSeed, ...)
{
  c.AddCount();
  try
  {
    await ....
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    // The exception is handled
  }
  c.Signal();  
}
```

My problem is that I no longer need the returned task. These tasks where collected and awaited to get the moment when all the work items are over, but now the countdown event can be used to indicate when the work is over.

My problem is that I am not sure how to integrate it into the Reactive chain. Essentially, the `GetPendingOrRunningTask` can be `async void`. And here I am stuck.

**EDIT 2**

[Strange appearance of a null entry in the list of tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412560/strange-appearance-of-a-null-entry-in-the-list-of-tasks)

Comment: Contrary to your statement, you won't ever have null tasks, and do not need to code against them.  There is also no reason to special case zero tasks.  `WhenAll` will simply be completed right away if there are no tasks in the collection.  `AsyncCountdownEvent` would make the code more complex, not less complex.

Comment: I believe `ToTask` in your code is typo. Otherwise that won't compile isn't it?

Comment: You may be right about `WhenAll`, but I am not delusional about the nulls. My unit tests failed because the list contained nulls. I cannot explain it, but I do not invent it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I am using the System.Reactive.Linq library. This is a Reactive extension and it compiles just fine.

Comment: @mark So what is the type of `tasks`? That is task or list?

Comment: @mark `ToTask` will work just fine, but you use the returned value as if it's a list, not a single task.  It's the subsequent usage that will fail.

Comment: @mark If you have null values then something is very wrong, and you should figure out what that is and fix the root cause, rather than trying to code around it.

Comment: Yes, @servy got the point. That's what I'm asking. Your code just won't compile.

Comment: Guys, my code compiles now already. More than that, it runs very well, if I ignore the possibility of nulls (which only occurred in unit tests). `ToList` returns `IObservable<IList<Task>>`, calling `ToTask` returns `IList<T>`. @SriramSakthivel - are you compiling with the Reactive libraries?

Comment: Where does `ToTask` returns `IList<T>`? I don't see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.threading.tasks.taskobservableextensions.totask%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (Not having a Visual studio right now). As name suggests `ToTask` returns a Task only unless am missing something. Also I believe servy has answered your question with his first and last comment(at the moment).

Comment: `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks.TaskObservableExtensions.ToTask` - `Task<TResult> ToTask<TResult>(this IObservable<TResult> observable)`. My mistake in the previous comment, `ToTask` returns `Task<IList<Task>>`, but the outer task is stripped by the `await` keyword. Sorry, servy's is reply is not satisfactory. I guess this is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @mark: Sounds like your mocking framework may be returning a `null` task. Try upgrading your mocking framework (no modern versions will do this - except VS stubs).

Comment: I wish it was my mocking framework. I use moq and I return `Task.Run` from it. Anyway, I left it as a mystery of mstest. What I really want is to get rid of the task list at all and use AsyncCountdownEvent instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary - mystery resolved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412560/strange-appearance-of-a-null-entry-in-the-list-of-tasks, but I still want to know if I could use your AsyncCountdownEvent here.

Comment: @mark: I don't see a benefit from doing so. Dave Sexton's answer looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Servy is correct that you need to solve the null `Task` problem at the source. Nobody wants to answer a question about how to workaround a problem that violates the contracts of a method that you've defined yourself and yet haven't provided the source for examination.

As for the issue about collecting tasks, it's easy to avoid with `Merge` if your method returns a generic `Task<T>`:

```
await taskSeedSource
  .Select(taskSeed => GetPendingOrRunningTask(taskSeed, createTask, onFailed, onSuccess, sem))
  .Where(task => task != null)  // According to you, this shouldn't be necessary.
  .Merge();
```

However, unfortunately there's no official `Merge` overload for the non-generic `Task` but that's easy enough to define:

```
public static IObservable<Unit> Merge(this IObservable<Task> sources)
{
  return sources.Select(async source =>
  {
    await source.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Unit.Default;
  })
  .Merge();
}
```

Comment: So, basically you are saying I do not need any countdown event at all.

Comment: Yea, did you try my example? (You only need the new `Merge` extension that I've shown if you're using a non-generic `Task`)

Comment: Which Merge method are you using? The reason I am asking is because I do not see a Merge extension method without arguments.

Comment: It's an extension method for `IObservable<Task<T>>`. I believe it was introduced in Rx 2.0. What version of Rx are you using?

Comment: 2.2.5.0 Could you give me the full type name of the extension class containing this method?

Comment: It's with all of the other extension methods. `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable`

Comment: OK, found it. I will try this approach. Though, I have a feeling using the countdown event might yield a more efficient code.

Comment: I am still working on it, but I definitely need to understand what is going on with the `null` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412560/strange-appearance-of-a-null-entry-in-the-list-of-tasks

Comment: What do you mean by "Merge locks inside"?

Comment: Could it be that a solution using `AsyncCountdownEvent` is going to result in less lock congestion than the one using `Merge`?

Comment: Based on your comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415098/why-is-it-possible-to-await-an-rx-observable the current solution is expected to throw if the source is empty.

Comment: How would you suggest to resolve the empty observable issue? Right now the code indeed throws.

Comment: You could use the `DefaultIfEmpty` operator.