# Strange appearance of a null entry in the list of tasks

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive

Here is the code involved:

```
private static async Task DoRunInOrderAsync<TTaskSeed>(SemaphoreSlim sem, IObservable<TTaskSeed> taskSeedSource, CreateTaskDelegate<TTaskSeed> createTask, OnTaskErrorDelegate<TTaskSeed> onFailed, OnTaskSuccessDelegate<TTaskSeed> onSuccess) where TTaskSeed : class
{
    var tasks = await taskSeedSource
        .Select(taskSeed => GetPendingOrRunningTask(taskSeed, createTask, onFailed, onSuccess, sem))
        .ToList()
        .ToTask();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
private static async Task GetPendingOrRunningTask<T>(T taskSeed, CreateTaskDelegate<T> createTask, OnTaskErrorDelegate<T> onFailed, OnTaskSuccessDelegate<T> onSuccess,
    SemaphoreSlim sem) where T : class
{
    Exception exc = null;
    await sem.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var task = createTask(taskSeed);
        if (task != null)
        {
            await task;
        }
        onSuccess(task, taskSeed);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exc = e;
    }

    sem.Release();

    if (exc != null)
    {
        onFailed(exc, taskSeed);
    }
}
```

Where:

- `Select` is `IObservable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)` from `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable`
- `ToList` is `IObservable<IList<TSource>> ToList<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)` from `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable`
- `ToTask` is `Task<TResult> ToTask<TResult>(this IObservable<TResult> observable)` from `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks.TaskObservableExtensions`
- System.Reactive.Linq version is 2.2.5.0

[image]

As far as I can see, everything is built, no stale binaries around. The error occurs often, but not always.

For the life of me, I cannot understand how the `tasks` list can contain `null` if the `GetPendingOrRunningTask` method is `async Task` ?

**EDIT**

[image]

So `ToList` injects `null`. How? Why? What am I doing wrong (besides programming for a living) ?

Comment: Are you aware of Rx's serialization contract? See §4.2 in the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219). The semaphore shouldn't be necessary because your `taskSeedSource` must not push overlapping notifications. If it is, then it's violating an important Rx contract which could cause race conditions within operators.

Comment: Note that if you want to run the tasks sequentially rather than concurrently, then project them into observables using `FromAsync` and call `Concat` rather than `ToList`.

Comment: It is sequentially only if the semaphore count is 1 initially. But it could be N, in which case I want to process at most N seeds concurrently until all the seeds are processed. The `InOrder` in the name is confusing a bit and is there for historic reasons.

Comment: Have just read the Rx's serialization contract. So, seems like I need to use the Serialize operator, right?

Comment: @DaveSexton - please, arrange your comment as an answer, I would like to credit you.

Comment: Yes, `Synchronize` will work. I don't need credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a race condition.

`.ToList()` calls the `List<T>` constructor.  The code is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d2ac2c19c9cf1d44).

If the number of elements in your `taskSeedSource` changes between the time the constructor starts and finishes, it's possible that you could end up with an inconsistent list.  In particular look at line 94.

```
ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
if( c != null) {
    int count = c.Count;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        _items = _emptyArray;
    }
    else {
        _items = new T[count];
        c.CopyTo(_items, 0);  /* it's possible there are now fewer elements in c */
        _size = count;
    }
}
```