# Why is it possible to await an Rx observable?

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have just noticed that the `await` keyword can be used with Rx Observable, for example:

```
await Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

I was pretty sure that it can only be used in conjunction with Tasks.

So what makes it possible? Is the knowledge of observables hard coded into the compiler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the compiler has no special knowledge of `IObservable<T>`. As per section 7.7.7.1 of the C# 5 specification if the object has a method or there is an extension method in scope named `GetAwaiter` that returns a type that implements `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion`, it can be awaited. See Steven Toub's article, [Await anything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx).

More specifically, from the spec

> The task of an await expression is required to be awaitable. An expression *t* is **awaitable** if one of the following holds:
>     - *t* is of compile time type dynamic
>     - *t* has an accessible instance or extension method called GetAwaiter with no parameters and no type parameters, and a return type A for which all of the following hold:
>      1. A implements the interface System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion (hereafter known as INotifyCompletion for brevity)
>      2. A has an accessible, readable instance property IsCompleted of type bool
>      3. A has an accessible instance method GetResult with no parameters and no type parameters

Note how this is similar to how `foreach` does not require `IEnumerable<T>` but simply a GetEnumerator method that returns a compatible object. This sort of duck typing is a performance optimization that allows value types to be used by the compiler without boxing. This can be used to avoid unnecessary allocations in performance sensitive code.

Comment: It may be worth noting that awaiting an observable only returns the last value when `OnCompleted` is called. And if there weren't any values in the sequence, an exception is thrown instead.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is because `System.Reactive.Linq` defines a `GetAwaiter` extension method on `IObservable`. As @mike z explained that allows you to await an `IObservable`. Here is the method:

```
public static AsyncSubject<TSource> GetAwaiter<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return s_impl.GetAwaiter<TSource>(source);
}
```

The returned type `AsyncSubject<T>` implements `INotifyCompletion` and has the `IsCompleted` property and `GetResult` method.

```
public sealed class AsyncSubject<T> : ISubject<T>, ISubject<T, T>, IObserver<T>, IObservable<T>, IDisposable, INotifyCompletion
{
    // Fields
    private Exception _exception;
    private readonly object _gate;
    private bool _hasValue;
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private bool _isStopped;
    private ImmutableList<IObserver<T>> _observers;
    private T _value;

    // Methods
    public AsyncSubject();
    private void CheckDisposed();
    public void Dispose();
    public AsyncSubject<T> GetAwaiter();
    public T GetResult();
    public void OnCompleted();
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation);
    private void OnCompleted(Action continuation, bool originalContext);
    public void OnError(Exception error);
    public void OnNext(T value);
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer);

    // Properties
    public bool HasObservers { get; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; }
```