# Covariance and contravariance on Tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task, covariance, contravariance

Given the followin snippet, i quite dont understand **WHY** what im going to achieve is not possible:

Interface:

```
public interface IEntityRepository<out T> : IRepository<IEntity> {

    void RequeryDataBase();

    IEnumerable<T> Search(string pattern);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> SearchAsync(string pattern);

    SearchContext Context { get; }

    string BaseTableName { get; }
  }
```

In `IRepository<IEntity>` are just simple generic **CRUD** defined.

I get an Error on this line: `Task<IEnumerable<T>> SearchAsync(string pattern);`

Error:

> method return type must be output safe. invalid variance: the type parameter T must be invariantly valid on Task

Please help me understand, why i cant use `<out T>` with a `Task<T>`

Comment: I think the result of the operation needs to be assigned to the task, making it an `<in T>`

Comment: @Jim but the result type is `iEnumerable<T>`, not just `T`....I would intuitivly think that this should work.

Comment: `Task<T>` is a class so it's invariant.

Comment: @RenéVogt I thought that too. The `Task` itself shouldnt care about, what comes back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Task<T>` is not covariant. Variance can only be applied to generic *interfaces* (and delegates, but that's not relevant here).

e.g. `Task<IEnumerable<Dog>>` *cannot* be assigned to `Task<IEnumerable<Animal>>`.  Because of this, your interface cannot be marked as covariant either.

You might want to see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant).

Comment: They can give all the explanations they want. I still feel like someone made the wrong call when introducing `Task<T>`, `ITask` but no `ITask<out T>`.

Answer (score 6):

When deciding on variance of a generic type argument in some generic interface, you have to take into account all uses of the generic type argument inside the interface. Each use may introduce some constraints regarding variance. This includes:

- Uses as input argument to a method - disallows covariance
- Uses as return value from a method - disallows contravariance
- Uses as part of other generic derivation, such as `Task<T>` - such use may disallow covariance, disallow contravariance, or both

I was using negative logic to emphasize that all these cases are basically introducing constraints. After the analysis, you will know whether any element has disallowed covariance and then your argument might not be declared as `out`. Conversely, if any element has disallowed contravariance, your argument might not be declared as `in`.

In your particular case, the first `Search` method returns `IEnumerable<T>`, rendering contravariance non-applicable. But then, SearchAsync is returning `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, and that usage introduces constraints that exist in the Task type - it is invariant, meaning that this time `out` is impossible as well.

The result is that your generic interface must be invariant on its generic argument type in order to satisfy signatures of all its methods.

Comment: I don't fully understand why there is not ITask<out T> interface. It would help with those issues.

Comment: @Toxantron because someone has to _set_ the result, so it can't be covariant. What I still don't see is how all this applies here, since the type in question is still `IEnumerable<T>` and not `T`. Why does the variance of `T` play any role in `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`?

Comment: @RenéVogt `Task` is invariant on `IEnumerable<T>`, which transitively means that T must not vary, despite the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` itself is covariant on `T`. The `Search` method returns plain `IEnumerable<T>` and that doesn't constraint variance. With only the `Search` method, entire interface could be covariant on `T`.

Comment: @RenéVogt sure it can. I design APIs like this all the time. Look at List<T> and IEnumerable<out T>. You operate on Task<T> but return ITask<out T>.

Comment: @Toxantron What is ITask<out T>?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Sadly non existent for some foggy reasons. And they argue it can't be changed now. I would expect someone creates `ITask<out T>` and whenever we come across an API that uses Task<T> we switch it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .NET Core or .NET 5 and onwards the solution is to use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` instead of `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`.

The covariant interface would look like:

```
public interface IEntityRepository<out T> : IRepository<IEntity> {

    void RequeryDataBase();

    IEnumerable<T> Search(string pattern);

    IAsyncEnumerable<T> SearchAsync(string pattern);

    SearchContext Context { get; }

    string BaseTableName { get; }
  }
```

More info about covariant async can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams).

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat and use

```
IObservable<out T>
```

which is **almost** the same as `Task<T>` but with a covariant type. It can always be converted to a task when you need it. You lose a little bit in the readability of the code because it is assumed ( and enforced ) with `Task<T>` that you only get one result but with `IObservable<T>` you can get many. However you can do

```
IObservable<T> o = ...
var foo = await o;
```

just the same as

```
Task<T> t = ...
var foo = await t;
```

Note that you'll need to include the `System.Reactive.Linq` namespace from the [Rx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq/) to make this work. It will add an extension method to `IObservable<>` that will make it awaitable.

Comment: Also, `Task` doesn't even implement `IObservable`

Comment: You can await an IObservable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415098/why-is-it-possible-to-await-an-rx-observable

Comment: Well, I'm guessing you're not talking about `System.IObservable` then ;)

Comment: As mentioned here, you need the extension method in `System.Reactive.Linq` for this to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27415346/1320374

Comment: Of course. Nobody uses IObservable without System.Reactive. Linq.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned before, `TResult` in `Task<TResult>` is not covariant. What you can do however is create a new `Task` instance using `ContinueWith`:

```
var intTask = Task.FromResult(42);
var objectTask = intTask.ContinueWith(t => (object) t.Result);

await objectTask; // 42
```